# llcp-dep p2p discovery and connections

Tags: nfc-p2p

I am working on a school project to connect the **pn532** with a nfc phone. I am using the seeedstudio nfc controller and the library they have, with some code that I am adding. My questions are related to the connection and discovery stage of the protocol.

Question 1: What to respond when the initiator sends a **CONNECT command to the DSAP = 1** "discovery service". Bellow I explain the results of the protocol.

Phones used to test were(gs4, note 2):

Situation 1:

- the phone sends me **05 20 06**  this is a CONNECT command to SAP =1 in the receiver device, then I respond with the CC command **81 84 2 2 0 78**.
- then they send me an IPDU with the URI of the application in the foreground, I keep sending command as per the llcp-snep protocol in the nfc forum and everything finish cool.
  *The problem is that I don't want the URI of the application in the foreground, I want the ***NDEF message*** data of that application instead.*

Situation 2:

- the phones send to the pn532 **11 20** , this is a CONNECT command to SAP =4 in the receiver device, then I respond with the command **CC 81 84 2 2 0 78**.
- After this the phone send me the NDEF data as is suppose to be.

  Now my questions are:

Why some times the phone send me the CONNECT command to the SAP =1 and some times to    SAP=4?

What command I have to response for the **05 20 06** ?

Comment: Regarding situation 1: Could it be that you didn't show us all the bytes received as part of the connect PDU? `06`is not a valid parameter TLV. Could it be that you actually received `05 20 06 0F 75 72 6E 3A 6E 66 63 3A 73 6E 3A 73 6E 65 70`?

Comment: Also are these two situations happening each for one specific device or are they happening randomly for both devices?

Comment: Also how do you setup the NDEF message that should be exchanged in the case that does not work?

Comment: I wish I receive a connection to the SNEP service but what I receive is: **20 5 20 6 1C 75 72 6E 3A 6E 66 63 3A 78 73 6E 3A 73 61 6D 73 75 6E 67 2E 63 6F 6D 3A 62 61 6E 64** as I wrote bellow this is asking for connection to the uri urn:nfc:xsn:samsung.com:band. I dont really know what it is however I typed the uri on my browser and it takes me to a samsung.com/band. This is a samsung url for country selection. I am wondering right now how to deny this service and tell the phone that what I want is communication over default SNEP server. Continuosly on GS4, randomly on note 2, never on GS3.

Comment: Okay, so you definitely don't want to connect that service. See the NFC Forum's LLCP specification for how to deny that request. Possibly the device will connect the SNEP service afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

When a CONNECT command is send to SAP 1 it means that the sender wants to perform service discovery and connection setup in one step. In this situation, a required information in the CONNECT command is the service name. If that service exists and is connectable the response would be a CC (Connection Complete) PDU to the SAP from which CONNECT was received and from 
the SAP that the named service is bound to. If a service with the requested name does not exist the answer would have to be a Disconnected Mode (DM) PDU with the appropriate reason code.

Unfortunately you have not provided full information about the CONNECT command received on SAP 1, at lest the service name length byte and the name itself are missing. As written, the CONNECT PDU is just invalid and should not be acknowledged.

Comment: Thanks for answer forks, what happen is Galaxy S4 sends me **5 20 6 1C 75 72 6E 3A 6E 66 63 3A 78 73 6E 3A 73 61 6D 73 75 6E 67 2E 63 6F 6D 3A 62 61 6E 64** this is a connection request to SAP 01 asking for the uri service: *urn:nfc:xsn:samsung.com/band*, actually I don't know what this service do. I was replying with the default port for SNEP which is SSAP 4. But after the Stephen response I realized that this CC command is wrong since SAP = 4, does not offers the service GS4 is asking for. I probably should send a DM command with reason no service available and see the next comming command.

Answer (score 1):

As expected the whole problem was solved. After the request for connection of the undesired service I sent the DM with reason 02 command and everything went normal. It took me some time to get the library to work with all phones together but finally I fixed it. Thanks for all the feedback